# How to get type of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemLink?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I want to get strings such as "Parent", "Child", "Related" and so on, but after a long time searching I haven't found any way.

The documentation I found is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemlink.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you need to check the WorkItemLink.LinkTypeEnd Property on that documentation page you provided. You can also find some information on [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgorti/archive/2007/09/26/querying-on-workitem-links-through-the-api.aspx).